# selenium: pc account lockout while running Test Automation in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, gradle

selenium: why do my pc account locks out when I run automation scripts? every time I have to go to the admin to get it unlocked

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Do you have solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Save the below code as `.vbs` and double click on the file when you want to keep the system unlocked.

```
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
do
    wscript.sleep 3000
    wshshell.sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}"
    wscript.sleep 3000
loop
```

Comment: Could you explain that how it work and why selenium make this scene?

Comment: The above snippet will trigger `NumLock` keypress every 3 seconds, which will keep the system awake as there is some activity happening on the machine continuously. If you would like to terminate this, Go to Taskbar and kill the `.vbs` related task. Btw, the snippet is nothing to do with Selenium, it will keep the machine active in general.